# ¿Está bien programada la función "buscar socio" que hice?

Tags: c++, algoritmos

Queremos trabajar con los datos de los socios de un club de fútbol:

- Número de socio (único para cada socio)
- Nombre, apellidos
- Sector (tribuna, preferencia, fondo, gol)
- Número de fila
- Número de asiento
- Antigüedad (año de inscripción).
- El club tiene como máximo 200 socios.

Implemente la función `Buscar_Socio()` para buscar los datos de un socio dado su número de socio. La función devolverá todos los datos del socio (No los imprime por pantalla). Además, la función devolverá `1` si ha encontrado al socio y `0` si no lo ha encontrado.

```
#include <iostream>
#define max 200
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct datos_club{
    char n_socio[8];
    char nombre[20];
    char apellido[20];
    char sector;
    int n_fila;
    int n_asiento;
    int antiguedad;

};

//prototipos
void leer_(datos_club A[],int n);
void mostrar_(datos_club A[],int n);
void Escribir_Socios(datos_club A[],int n);


//funcion principal
int main(){
    struct datos_club datos[max];

    int i;
    int n;
    char n_socios[8];

    cout<<"numero de personas: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"DATOS DE LOS SOCIOS\n\n";
    leer_(datos,n);
    cout<<"MOSTRAR DATOS DE SOCIO\n\n";
    mostrar_(datos,n);
    cout<<"Mostrando la persona que tiene una antiguedad mayor que 5\n\n";
    Escribir_Socios(datos,n);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

//Definicion de funciones
void leer_(datos_club A[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        cout<<"codigo de socio: ";
        cin>>A[i].n_socio;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"nombre: ";
        cin.getline(A[i].nombre,20);
        cout<<"apellido: ";
        cin.getline(A[i].apellido,20);
        cout<<"sector t/p/f/g : ";
        cin>>A[i].sector;
        cout<<"n_fila: ";
        cin>>A[i].n_fila;
        cout<<"n_asiento: ";
        cin>>A[i].n_asiento;
        cout<<"antiguedad(años): ";
        cin>>A[i].antiguedad;
        cout<<"\n\n";
    }
}
void Escribir_Socios(datos_club A[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].antiguedad>5){
            if(A[i].sector=='p'){
            cout<<"codigo del socio: "<<A[i].nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"apellido: "<<A[i].apellido<<endl;
            cout<<"n_fila: "<<A[i].n_fila<<endl;
            cout<<"n_asiento: "<<A[i].n_asiento<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}   

void mostrar_(datos_club A[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    cout<<"codigo del socio: "<<A[i].n_socio<<endl;
    cout<<"nombre: "<<A[i].nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"apellido: "<<A[i].apellido<<endl;
    cout<<"sector t/p/f/g : "<<A[i].sector<<endl;
    cout<<"n_filas: "<<A[i].n_fila<<endl;
    cout<<"n_asiento: "<<A[i].n_asiento<<endl;
    cout<<"antiguedad: "<<A[i].antiguedad<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
bool Buscar_Socios(datos_club A[],int n){
    char codigo[6];

    cout<<"ingrese codigo :";
    cin>>codigo;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].n_socio==codigo){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas Ricardo. Te agradeceríamos que concretaras algo más tu pregunta. Una cosa es tener un código que no funciona y no sabes por qué y otra muy diferente pedir abiertamente que te hagamos la tarea....

Comment: Además, no se gana nada publicando todo lo que llevas hecho. Lo ideal es un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema que tienes. Pero como te comento, aquí no se hacen deberes.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que se presenta en el código?

Comment: el problema que tengo es que me piden crear una funcion que ingreseando el codigo me devuelva 1 si existe y 0 si no(al momento que ingreso el codigo del socio no me aparece nada)..ya edite mi codigo ahi aparece la funcion que cree.

Comment: @RicardoTovar pero sigues sin decir cual es el problema. la funcion pareceria estar bien. asi a simple vista...

Answer (score 2):

```
bool Buscar_Socios(datos_club A[],int n){
    char codigo[6];

    cout<<"ingrese codigo :";
    cin>>codigo;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].n_socio==codigo){ // <<--- AQUI!!!
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

La línea comentada no va a funcionar como esperas porque el operador comparación no va a comparar dos cadenas... simplemente estás comparando la dirección de memoria apuntada por ambos punteros.

Para comparar cadenas *crudas*, es decir, al estilo C, debes usar funciones de comparación características de C, como `strcmp`:

```
if( strcmp(A[i].n_socio,codigo) == 0)
```

Sin embargo todo sería más cómodo si integrases C++ correctamente y sustituyeses `char[]` por `std::string`:

```
struct datos_club{
    std::string n_socio;
    std::string nombre;
    std::string apellido;
    char sector;
    int n_fila;
    int n_asiento;
    int antiguedad;
};

bool Buscar_Socios(datos_club A[],int n){
    std::string codigo;

    cout<<"ingrese codigo :";
    cin>>codigo;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].n_socio==codigo){ // Ahora sí funciona
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Otro detalle a corregir en la función son los valores de retorno:

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].n_socio==codigo){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0; 
        }
    }
```

Si analizas con tranquilidad ese bucle verás que en la primera iteración, o devuelve 1 o devuelve 0, es decir, **nunca** va a comparar más de un elemento. Si tienes suerte y el elemento buscado es el primero entonces retornará `true`, mientras que si el elemento buscado se encuentra en cualquier otra posición la función devolverá `false`, lo cual es erróneo.

Lo lógico es que el retorno de *no encontrado*  se produzca fuera del bucle, es decir, una vez que has finalizado la búsqueda sin encontrar lo que buscas:

```
bool Buscar_Socios(datos_club A[],int n){
    std::string codigo;

    cout<<"ingrese codigo :";
    cin>>codigo;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].n_socio==codigo){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Y para rematar, en C++ el tipo `bool` va acompañado de sus valores correspondientes: `true` y `false`... así que mejor usar dichos valores en vez de `1` y `0`:

```
bool Buscar_Socios(datos_club A[],int n){
    std::string codigo;

    cout<<"ingrese codigo :";
    cin>>codigo;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i].n_socio==codigo){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false; 
}
```

Y con estos cambios la función ya debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: teniendo esta función, cómo se formularía en main para obtener los datos del nombre introducido? De ante mano gracias la por ayuda.

Comment: @Neon lo que tienes que ver son los errores que comento en la respuesta porque son los mismos que has cometido tú